# Prime Ng Autocomplete drop down position not working

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, primeng

I used the [PrimeNG Autocomplete](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/autocomplete) ,I faced some conflict , when I used this style autocomplete drop downs is take a down position ,

Image description here

[image]

Anyone know how to do that correctly ?

Thanks

```
<div class="col">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label >Please Select a Tag</label>
                            <p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="brand" [suggestions]="filteredBrands" (completeMethod)="filterBrands($event)" [size]="30"
                                            [minLength]="1" placeholder="Hint: type 'Gold' or 'G'" [dropdown]="true"[style]="{'width':'100%'}" [inputStyle]="{'width':'100%'}" class="p-autocomplete" >
                              <ng-template let-brand pTemplate="item">
                                <div class="ui-helper-clearfix" style="border-bottom:0px solid #D5D5D5">

                                  <div style="font-size:18px;float:right;margin:10px 10px 0 0">{{brand}}</div>
                                </div>
                              </ng-template>
                            </p-autoComplete>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

**style**

```
.p-autocomplete{
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Just remove the `[inputStyle]="{'width':'100%'}"` from `<p-autoComplete>` tag. It will work fine. Check the [stackblits](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hgt8yd)

You are giving 100% width to input field that why icon going down. Hope it helps.